# Retry fetch request doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

This is the current code and what I've come up with:

```js
function getToken() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let res = await fetch(url);

            if (res.status === 418) {
                setTimeout(getToken, 1000);
            } else {
                let token = await res.text();
                console.log("1", token);
                resolve(token);
            }
        } catch(e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}

async function test() {
    let token = await getToken();
    console.log("2", token);
}

test();
```

It logs `1 <token>` but it doesn't log the other part like its supposed to (`2 <token>`). Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: `new Promise(async (` seems redundant? An `async` function will return a promise

Comment: and using 418 seems mysterious to use in 2021. what's the usecase?

Comment: If I don't use promise it would log `2 undefined`

Comment: @Wolfy what if you return the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My *very* naive approach would be a mix of a "sleep" function and standard async/await syntax (no need to mix `then` into it).

This does not take into consideration a possible infinite loop if the URL consistently returns a 418 http code.

The biggest thing to note is that I am returning `getToken()` in the retry and also returning `token` in the else. If we don't do this `token` inside `test` will always be undefined.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function getToken() {
  try {
    let res = await fetch('https://httpstat.us/200');

    if (res.status === 418) {
      await sleep(1000);
      return getToken();
    } else {
      let token = await res.text();
      console.log("1", token);
      return token;
    }
  } catch (e) {}
};

async function test() {
  let token = await getToken();
  console.log("2", token);
}

test();
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function get(url, retryStatusCode) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let found = false;
        while (found !== true) {
            try {
                await sleep(1000);
                await fetch(url).then(res => { 
                    let text = res.text(); 
                    let status = res.status;
                    if (status !== retryStatusCode) {
                        found = true;
                        resolve(text);
                    }
                });
            } catch (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Then `await get(url, 404)`.

Comment: Why put an async function inside a `then`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox My bad, fixed in next edit

Answer (score -1):

Use then

```
await fetch(url).then(res=>console.log(res).catch(err=>console.log(err);
```

I'm just logging the res here, you can do whatever you want with it

Comment: I think you're missing a `)` after your first console.log, and another after the second (also... given you're awaiting fetch()... there's not much reason to use .then/.catch)

Comment: Yeah,, I saw my mistaked